# How to set a key with Expiry using redisgo Api

Tags: go, redigo

How use below Redis command in GoLang using redisgo.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set hello 1 EX 10 
OK
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

I have tried using below,

```
_, err = conn.Do("EXPIRE", key, ttl)
```

Is there any way to set ttl, when setting the key?

Comment: "Is there any way to set ttl, when setting the key?" Yes, exactly like on the cmdline: Do("SET", key, value, "EX", 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conn.Do("SETEX", "mykey", time, value)`
Ex.
`conn.Do("SETEX", "mykey", 600, value)`

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.